# Writing XML-File with Jpa

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb

Im using  JAXB.marshal(list,file.xml) to write an XML file. It works perfectly and i can import the data into excel or access. but all columns are imported as string, although some are double or date. for the date field i used the @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE) annotation. how can i save the datatyp in the xml file?
or do i have to save it in a XML Schema? if so, can i auto-generate it with jpa?

Edit: I managed to generate a xml and xsd file:

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="eintragListe">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Eintrag" type="eintrag" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="eintrag">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="art" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="betrag" type="xs:double"/>
  <xs:element name="datum" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="pa" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="typ" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="verwendung" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:eintragListe xmlns:ns2="www">
    <Eintrag>
        <art>Einmalig</art>
    <betrag>27.0</betrag>
    <datum>2012-06-01T00:00:00+02:00</datum>
    <id>601</id>
    <pa>-1</pa>
    <typ>Ausgabe</typ>
    <verwendung>Irgendswas</verwendung>
</Eintrag>
<Eintrag>
    <art>Einmalig</art>
    <betrag>17.0</betrag>
    <datum>2012-06-01T00:00:00+02:00</datum>
    <id>502</id>
    <pa>-1</pa>
    <typ>Ausgabe</typ>
    <verwendung>Irgendwasanderes</verwendung>
    </Eintrag>
</ns2:eintragListe>
```

i now wanted to import these files into excel, but i always get an error, that the schema doesnt fit to the xml file. is there a solution? thanks four your help :)

Comment: If you can post what you need the XML file to look like so that it will import properly into excel or access, then I can help with the JAXB mapping part.

Comment: I've no idea, if the structure and data is stored in the same file or not :(

Comment: If Excel/Access offer an export to XML feature you could set up some same data and export it to see what the XML would look like.

Comment: i just tried that, but it really confused me :S

Comment: ill just open a new thread since my question changed..